# Get all employees that belong to exact same location list as the passed in employee

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table called `EmployeeLocationAssn`:

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeLocationAssn (
[EmployeeLocationAssnId] [int]  IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
[EmployeeId] [int] NOT NULL,
[LocationId] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

This table contains data for employees and their associated locations.

```
INSERT INTO EmployeeLocationAssn (EmployeeId, LocationId) VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT INTO EmployeeLocationAssn (EmployeeId, LocationId) VALUES (1, 2)
INSERT INTO EmployeeLocationAssn (EmployeeId, LocationId) VALUES (2, 1)
INSERT INTO EmployeeLocationAssn (EmployeeId, LocationId) VALUES (2, 2)
INSERT INTO EmployeeLocationAssn (EmployeeId, LocationId) VALUES (3, 1)
INSERT INTO EmployeeLocationAssn (EmployeeId, LocationId) VALUES (3, 2)
INSERT INTO EmployeeLocationAssn (EmployeeId, LocationId) VALUES (4, 1)
INSERT INTO EmployeeLocationAssn (EmployeeId, LocationId) VALUES (4, 2)
INSERT INTO EmployeeLocationAssn (EmployeeId, LocationId) VALUES (4, 3)
INSERT INTO EmployeeLocationAssn (EmployeeId, LocationId) VALUES (4, 4)
INSERT INTO EmployeeLocationAssn (EmployeeId, LocationId) VALUES (5, 3)
INSERT INTO EmployeeLocationAssn (EmployeeId, LocationId) VALUES (5, 4)
INSERT INTO EmployeeLocationAssn (EmployeeId, LocationId) VALUES (6, 1)
INSERT INTO EmployeeLocationAssn (EmployeeId, LocationId) VALUES (6, 2)
INSERT INTO EmployeeLocationAssn (EmployeeId, LocationId) VALUES (6, 3)
INSERT INTO EmployeeLocationAssn (EmployeeId, LocationId) VALUES (6, 4)
```

I want to get all employees that have the exactly the same location list as passed in employee id.

Example:
If the user passes `EmployeeId = 1`, then the query should return all employees that have the same locations.

```
Output: 
@EmployeeId = 1
1
2
3
```

Employees 4 and 6 has locations 1, 2, 3 & 4. It doesn't exactly match with location 1 & 2 that Employee 1 has and Employee 5 has a completely different location list (3, 4).

```
@EmployeeId = 4
4
6
```

Employees 1, 2, and 3 has locations 1 & 2. It doesn't exactly match with locations 1, 2, 3 & 4 that Employee 4 has and Employee 5 has a partial location list (3, 4). Only Employee 4 & 6 has the same location list (1, 2, 3, 4).

```
@EmployeeId = 5
5
```

Employees 1, 2, and 3 has locations 1 & 2. It doesn't exactly match with locations 3 & 4 that Employee 5 has and Employee 4 & 6 has a bigger location list (1, 2, 3, 4).

I started writing a query but got all confused, here is what I have which of course is not correct.

```
DECLARE @EmployeeId int = 1

Select ELA.EmployeeId, ELA.LocationId from EmployeeLocationAssn ELA
Where not exists 
(Select ELA.LocationId from EmployeeLocationAssn ELA2 where ELA2.EmployeeId = @EmployeeId
EXCEPT
Select ELA.LocationId from EmployeeLocationAssn ELA3 where ELA3.EmployeeId = ELA.EmployeeId)
and ELA.EmployeeId <> @EmployeeId;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`string_agg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (if using SQL Server 2017+) to compare the Employees:

```
declare @EmployeeId int = 1;

with cte as (
    select E.EmployeeId
        , string_agg(E.LocationId,',') within group (order by LocationId asc) LocationGroup
    from EmployeeLocationAssn E
    group by E.EmployeeId
)
select EmployeeId
from cte
where LocationGroup = (select LocationGroup from cte where EmployeeId = @EmployeeId);
```

Or `for xml path` if using a lower version:

```
declare @EmployeeId int = 1;

with cte as (
  select E.EmployeeId, 
    substring(
      (
        select ',' + convert(varchar(12),E1.LocationId) as [text()]
        from #EmployeeLocationAssn E1
        where E1.EmployeeId = E.EmployeeId
        order by E1.LocationId
        for xml path ('')
      ), 2, 1000) LocationGroup
  from #EmployeeLocationAssn E
  group by E.EmployeeId
)
select EmployeeId
from cte
where LocationGroup = (select LocationGroup from cte where EmployeeId = @EmployeeId);
```

*[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=56eeb92d70a8ab21556d73f97aa75ca6)*

Comment: I want to get a result 1, 2 and 3 since these match exactly like employee id 1's locations which is locationids 1 & 2. EmployeeId 4, 5 and 6 shouldn't show up since they have more than one match. Hope I am able to explain it properly.

Comment: @SriReddy ok try now.

Comment: Any recommendation on these queries with respect to performance. I am expecting 1000x50=50000 records and in the future, it might grow more.

Comment: @SriReddy they probably won't perform that well TBH... the LocationGroup value has to be computed for the entire table. You might find Stu's solution quicker. Best thing to do it try then both in query analyser and see the percentages. Although it depends whether you used the `string_agg` solution or the `for xml` solution?

Comment: Yeah in a rough test Stu's solution performed over twice as fast. And Bilals solution performs twice as fast again (once its fixed as per Stus comments).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative query that works for your criteria, checking the Locations match those of the selected employee, are not in those not used by the selected employee, and the number of locations match.

```
 declare @EmployeeId int=1

       ;with x as (
            select locationid, Count(*) over() Qty
            from EmployeeLocationAssn
            where employeeid=@EmployeeId group by LocationId
        )
        select distinct EmployeeId
        from x join EmployeeLocationAssn e on e.LocationId=x.LocationId
        where e.employeeid not in (
            select EmployeeId
            from EmployeeLocationAssn e2
            where LocationId not in (select locationId from x)
        )
        and x.qty=(select Count(*) from EmployeeLocationAssn e3 where e3.EmployeeId=e.EmployeeId)
```

Comment: Semi-colons are a statement *terminator* not *begininator* :)

Comment: @DaleK yes indeed - except they are required with CTE if not the first statment in the batch - otherwise sqlserver throws `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.`

Comment: Just terminate the previous statement (declare) as they are designed for :) one should be semi-colon terminating *all* SQL statements by now.

Comment: True, force of habbit and something to do with old dogs and new tricks I guess ;)

Comment: Its good to teach the newbies good habits.

Comment: Good for everyone regardless of experience - no one is never not learning :)